# Reverse a 1d array output from a function (or get the last value), without VBA?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010

Suppose I have a UDF `MyFunc()` which is too costly to call more than once, `MyFunc()` returns an array.  By default, if applied to a single cell then the first value in the array is used.  I want the last value of the array.

So, is it possible to:

- (a) reverse the array so that the last value is used, or
- (b) just grab the last value directly?

Comment: You could use a Static variable in your UDF to cache the array between calls (assuming the array doesn't change frequently)

Comment: This is a good technique that I infact use in some of my UDFs.  In this particular case I was just trying to tease out my non-UDF/non-VBA options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use INDEX to return a certain position

If you know the position you want you could use

```
=INDEX(Myfunct(),2)
```

for the second position etc

For the last position of unknown size

```
=INDEX(Myfunct(),COUNTA(Myfunct()))
```

second last

```
=INDEX(Myfunct(),COUNTA(Myfunct())-1)
```

Comment: brettdj - if the size is unknown, is there anyway around a double call to the function?

Comment: If you were using the function many times, you could extract the length to a single cell (or range name) and then use that reference once rather that twice in each call. I cant see a way around using it twice for a single call.

Comment: after a closer look it seems that I do in fact know the number of items in the array.  thanks so much!